# Why can't iPad download mp3 files?

Tags: asp.net

I have E-Commerce website and uploaded some mp3 files in it, and customers can download the mp3 files to a PC, but when they try to download them to an iPad, iPad can't download them.

The code for downloading files is the following

```
public static void DownloadAudio(string url)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler is basePage)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        string fileDiskPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(url);
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileDiskPath);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", fileInfo.Name));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(fileDiskPath);
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Note: This method is not supporting user controls.  Consider supporting user controls by getting the parent page from user control.");
    }
}
```

Comment: So...what happens when a user on an iPad tries to download an mp3?

Comment: Message appears says "safari cannot download the file"

Answer (score 1):

The Safari browser on the iPad will only let users download a file for which they have an installed application that can handle it - by default no built-in iOS app will handle arbitrary downloads or MP3 files.

If your visitors have an app like GoodReader installed, then Mobile Safari will prompt the user to open the download in GoodReader.

Comment: but, i tried to download mp3 files from another sites and the downloading operation succeeded, so i can't determine where is the problem exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try using the official MIME type.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "audio/mpeg";
```

Comment: I already tried this, but it failed also